# Erro ao consumir web service com ajax(JSON) no Cordova app

Tags: .net, web-service, apache-cordova

Boa noite construí um web servisse onde existe um método que recebe um parâmetro string, o qual uso para serializar para uma classe conforme segue:

```java
/*parte da classe cliente*/
public  class Cliente
    {
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string  Descricao { get; set; }
        public string DataNascimento { get; set; }
        public int Sexo { get; set; }
        public string Endereco { get; set; }
        public string Bairro { get; set; }
        public string Telefone { get; set; }
     }
```

Aqui o método no Ws que recebe e deserializa() o json para a classe acima citada:

```java
 public string  InsereCliente(string Cliente)
    {      
        string resultado = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            Util.GravaErroLog(Cliente, "Teste para ver se a string esta chegando");
            List<string> Rec = new List<string>();
            SerializadorDAO dao = new SerializadorDAO();
            var Cli = dao.DesSerializarUnitario(Cliente);//dao.DeSerializarJson<List<Cliente>>(Cliente);
            Rec.Add(Util.InsereCliente(Cli));
            resultado = dao.SerializaDadosJson<string>(Rec);
        }
        catch( Exception ex)
        {
            Util.GravaErroLog(ex.Message, "InsereCliente");
        }


        return resultado;
    }
```

Aqui o método q realiza o processo de deserializacão(na verdade já tentei de duas formas porém  so roda no teste local se requisito via ajax de o erro que pra frente mostro).

```java
/*Primeiro teste*/
public string  InsereCliente(string Cliente)
    {      
        string resultado = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            Util.GravaErroLog(Cliente, "Teste para ver se a string esta chegando");
            List<string> Rec = new List<string>();
            SerializadorDAO dao = new SerializadorDAO();
            var Cli = dao.DesSerializarUnitario(Cliente);//dao.DeSerializarJson<List<Cliente>>(Cliente);
            Rec.Add(Util.InsereCliente(Cli));
            resultado = dao.SerializaDadosJson<string>(Rec);
        }
        catch( Exception ex)
        {
            Util.GravaErroLog(ex.Message, "InsereCliente");
        }


        return resultado;
    }
```

Aqui o outro método de desserializacao mas usando  listas

```java
/* 2 Teste */

public List<T>DeSerializarJson <T>(string json) {
  var Lista=new List<T>();
  try {
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser=new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
    using (MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json))) {
      Lista=(List<T>)ser.ReadObject(ms);
    }
    ;
  }
  catch(Exception ex) {
    GravaErroLog(ex.Message, "DeserializarJson");
  }
  return Lista;
}
```

aqui a parte do cliente no cordova primeiro popula o objeto:

```js
var Cliente;

function PopulaClienteJson() {
  var D = $('#DataNasc').val().split('-');
  var data = '';
  var dia = D[2]
  var mes = D[1];
  var Ano = D[0];
  data = mes + '/' + dia + '/' + Ano;
  Cliente = [{
    Descricao: new String($('#descricao').val()),
    Endereco: new String($('#Endereco').val()),
    DataNascimento: new String(data),
    Numero: new String($('#Numero').val()),
    Bairro: new String($('#Bairro').val()),
    Cidade: new String($('#Cidade').val()),
    Cep: new String($('#Cep').val()),
    Email: new String($('#Email').val()),
    RG: new String($('#RG').val()),
    CPF: new String($('#CPF').val()),
    Profissao: new String($('#Profissao').val()),
    ComoConheceu: new String($('#Info').val())
  }]

}
```

depois a chamada Ajax

```js
var UrlPadrao = "http://192.168.2.42/WebUltra/webOrcs.asmx/InsereCliente";

function EnviaCliente() {

  var json1 = JSON.stringify(Cliente);
  alert(json1);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: UrlPadrao,
    data: json1,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      PopulaCodigoCliente(data)
    },
    error: function(data) {
      erroJson(data)
    }
  });
```

e  por fim o erro :

```
"{"Message":"O tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2
    [
      [System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],
      [System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]
    ]' não é suportado para desserialização de uma matriz.",
  "StackTrace":"   
      em System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, IList& convertedList)
      em System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)
      em System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
      em System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)
      em System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}"
```

há já ia ia esquecendo o resultado da criação do json

```
[ 
    {
        "Codigo":"0", 
        "Descricao":"wdadeqwdqwe", 
        "Endereco":"aa", 
        "DataNascimento":"2009-01-01", 
        "Numero":"3", 
        "Bairro":"aa",  
        "Cidade":"aaa", 
        "Cep":"33", 
        "Email":"a", 
        "RG":"33", 
        "CPF":"33", 
        "Profissao":"aa", 
        "ComoConheceu":"aa"
    }
]
```

então se  eu for no navegador e chamar  o método e passar o parâmetro ele insere normal, porém na chamada via ajax da erro. Por quer?

Answer (score 0):

A solução desta questão foi  a seguinte:
Tive que fazer a correção do parametro que estava sendo enviado pela chamada ajax que segue:

```js
function EnviaCliente() {

  var json1 = JSON.stringify(Cliente);
  alert(json1);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: UrlPadrao,
    data: json1,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      PopulaCodigoCliente(data)
    },
    error: function(data) {
      erroJson(data)
    }
  });
```

para este modelo que respeita o nome do parametro do WS e o tipo de dados que deve ser passado pelo parâmetro na chamada Ajax:

```js
function EnviaCliente() {
   
    var json1 = JSON.stringify(Cliente);
    alert(json1);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: UrlPadrao,
        data: '{Cliente:"Teste de envio"}',//aqui a correcao 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        datatype: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) { PopulaCodigoCliente(data) },
        error: function (data) { erroJson(data) }
    });
```

agora irei quantificar os parâmetros do objeto Json1 e descreve-los no ws para que enfim possa usar este objeto.
Obrigado "pela ajuda"